# 404 Page Categories Not Found

Tags: magento2, url, 404-page

We have problems with page 404 page and our URLs have two formats without knowing why.

See the example below.

[www.mywebsite.com/catalog/category/view/s/herboristerie/id/419/](http://www.mywebsite.com/catalog/category/view/s/herboristerie/id/419/) (Okay)
[www.mywebsite.com/herboristerie.html](http://www.mywebsite.com/herboristerie.html) (404 Not found)

Comment: try to save category again, it will regenerate URL.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I have a multilingual site and the URLs work for the other stores except for the main one.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue too.

So I have to take MySQL dump ( for backup purpose ).

Then Truncate url_rewite ( using PHPMyAdmin and also uncheck foreign key while truncate )

Then install this [URL Generator](https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls) using the composer ( read guideline ).

After that upgrade and deploy and then

run the command one by one

```
php bin/magento regenerate:category:path
php bin/magento regenerate:category:url
php bin/magento regenerate:product:url
```

Work for me. Hope this might help you. ( Use staging site and take backup )